# Can't get PDO SQL query to work

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I can't get this query to work. It only shows the first DB entry. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

/* prepare */

```
$sql = "SELECT personal.firstName, personal.lastName, etc. 
        FROM personal 
        LEFT JOIN exam 
        ON personal.P_ID=exam.P_ID 
        LEFT JOIN contact 
        ON exam.P_ID=contact.P_ID 
        WHERE exam.Level = ? 
        AND exam.Centre!='' ORDER BY exam.Centre";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

/* Execute */
                $stmt->execute(array($level));

```
/* Fetch */
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    





/*  Display  */
                    echo '<table>
                         <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Surname</td>
                    <td>Paid?</td>
                    <td>Etc</td>
                    <td>Etc</td>
                    <td>Etc</td>
                        </tr>';
```

if ($row) 
          { 
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)

```
              {
                echo '<td>';
                echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
            }
               echo '</tr>';
          }
       echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You don't need to bind a parameter for an empty string; and the other one should be `exam.Level=:level`, I think.

Comment: `WHERE exam.Level = :level`

Comment: And i dont see a `:centre` placeholder in your query...

Comment: Thanks. I amended to exam.Level = :level.

How do I use :centre if it's an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

A simple tutorial for you to get it right.

1. Take your mysql query that works

   ```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = $a AND b = '$b'";
   ```
2. Make **sure** it works. If not - make it work first.
3. Take out every variable you interpolate in it (*along with **all** corresponding formatting, including slashes **and** quotes*), and put a question mark in place of them.

   ```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = ? AND b = ?";
   ```
4. Move these variables into `execute()` in the form of array

   ```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = ? AND b = ?";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($a,$b));
   ```
5. Everything works.
6. If still not - [configure your PDO and PHP in order to see errors if any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858), read the error message and take appropriate action.

To get your data in the proper format you have to use proper fetch method

```
     $data = $stm->fetchAll();
     foreach ($data as $row) {
       echo $row['id'];
       // do whatever
     }
```

Please refer to [tag wiki for other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: Also,if you have `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `true`, you can use [PDOStatement::debugDumpParams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) **after** the `execute()`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to run, but it only shows the first entry in the database. Surely I don't need to loop to show ALL entries that meet the criteria?

Comment: @user2304574 just use proper fetch method. To get all entries you have to use `$stmt1->fetchAll()` instead of fetch() which gets you only one record

Comment: `fetchAll()` just wipes my data and replaces it with "Array".

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at PDO as well, but from your code I noticed that there is no `:centre` in the query there, so that parameter won't bind?

Another thing is in `WHERE exam.Level:level`, are you sure you meant this and not: `WHERE exam.Level = :level` ?

Comment: Thanks. I amended to `exam.Level = :level` but it still doesn't work. 

And how do I use a parameter for an empty string? e.g. `exam.Centre!=''`